# Interactive mapping zip codes in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame of zipcodes and other categorical information

```
Dealer  Zipcode
A       95605
A       93636
B       93534
B       93201
```

Is there a way to map zip codes in R like this screenshot? And possibly color the area by the categorical variable? I have only ever used the leaflet package to do mapping .

[image]

Comment: I would look for a GIS data source. That looks like Sacramento, CA so you might find that this https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8d2012a2016e484dafaac0451f9aea24 will work for you if you have ArcGIS. The other option would be to digitize the map that you have (which is tedious). This is more suited to GIS software than R.

Comment: So the screenshot is just a random one I found of what I would like the map to kind of look like but I am open to anything. The main thing I wanted is mapping zip codes, most of which are California

Comment: You'll need is a shapefile of the zipcodes' polygons and a data.frame/.table with information about each zipcode. Then read the manuals/follow the tutorials of the `sf` and `leaflet`-packages and you are probably good to go.